# How to limit the number of FlowFiles in a loop?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am submitting FlowFiles to an external web service for processing that can take a significant amount of time. The process is:

1. Submit the FlowFile to the web service.
2. Check the status of the job
3. If status is "success", continue on to the rest of the NiFi flow
4. If status is "running", penalize the FlowFile for some time, then go to step 2.

I'd like to be able to limit the number of FlowFiles being processed by the web service, since they can be submitted much faster than they can be processed. I don't want to just turn down the rate of step 1, because that will just slow down the process if the files are small and processed quickly.

I tried using small sizes in the queues in the loop, but the whole thing basically gridlocked, where no processor could run because the downstream one was full.

[image: Current flow]

Comment: you can use `ControlRate` to control the rate at which data is transferred to follow-on processors OR `wait-notify` to implement gate close-open like mechanism.

Comment: ^ that being said - "can be submitted much faster than they can be processed" - is a bit open-ended - if you're ending up with GBs of FFs stuck in a 'waiting' phase, then you might need to rethink how you are queuing waiting FFs - you can start by increasing the queue size of the penalise queue so that it has more room before causing back pressure on the flow - but if you're scaling up, you might want to look at an external queuing mechanism, e.g. kafka

Comment: It's not the rate that I'm trying to control, exactly. I can control that by controlling the rate of the first processor. It's more like, "don't process any more files unless there are fewer than 10 currently being processed by the web service". Putting it like that, I'll probably have to go with some sort of wait/notify setup.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to change the Rate of the Flow.

1. Use *[Controll Rate Processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ControlRate/index.html)* (Allows only n Flowfiles to Pass per x seconds)
2. Change *Concurrent Tasks* in the Processor Configuration (With this option the Processor can handle more threads simultanious. So it processes n Flowfiles parallel.
3. Change *Run Duration* in the Processor Configuration (This option adds a Delay to the Flowfile when it is processed so every Flowfile that is Processes takes the same time)
4. Change Yield Duration (This adds delay before the Processor processes the Flowfile)
5. If you need a strict workflow with no delays you can use wait-notify Pattern